# Parameter equation $x=\ln(|x-a|)$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Find out how many solutions has an equation 
$$
x=\ln(|x-a|)
$$
depending on the value of $a$

**My approach:**

I see that as $\exp$ is an injective function the equation can be reduced to
$$
e^x=|x-a|
$$
and I also know that the line $y=1+x$  is tangent to function $e^x$ in $x=0$ so I would say that the initial equation has

1. solution for $a\in(-1,\infty)$
2. solutions for $x=-1$
3. solutions for $x\in(-\infty,-1)$

but I don't know how to prove this facts formally using the real-analysis theorems.

Comment: I don't think you need a better or more "rigorous" proof. A proof using "Analysis theorems" would be unnecessarily complicated and hard to follow. In my opinion, nothing can replace a clean geometric argument.All you need to make it more precise is to invoke the IVT to justify that you have a root "on the left side" of the graph of $y=|x-a|$ and two more if $a<-1$. To justify the third root, you just notice that $e^x>>|x-a|$ at infinity in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) := |x-a|e^{-x}$. Then $x$ is a solution of your equation iff $f(x) = 1$. We have $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$, $f(a) = 0$, $f(-\infty) = +\infty$ and $f(+\infty) = 0$. On $(-\infty,a)$ we have $f(x) = (a-x)e^{-1}$ and thus $f'(x) = -(1+a-x)e^{-1} < 0$. Therefore, there is always exactly one solution in $(-\infty,a)$. Consider $f$ on $(a,\infty)$. There we have $f(x) = (x-a)e^{-x}$ with derivative $f'(x) = (1-(x-a))e^{-x}$. This one has a zero exactly at $x = 1+a$ and $f(1+a) = e^{-(1+a)}$ (here we have a maximum!). So, $f(1+a) < 1$ iff $a> -1$. This shows that you are right.